# Redirect Standard Input To Large File in Powershell - Memory Consumption

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, stdin, large-files

In PowerShell, the normal way of redirecting standard input to a file is to pipe the contents of the file:

```
Get-Content input-file.txt | Write-Host
```

However, if the file is very large, PowerShell begins to consume a large amount of memory. Using a small `-ReadCount` seems to speed up how quickly `Get-Content` starts feeding rows into the command, but the memory consumption is still large.

Why is the memory usage so high? Is it that PowerShell is retaining the contents of the file in memory, even though it doesn't need to? Is there some way to mitigate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will read the file in line by line by using the .NET [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aetdk20.aspx) class and send each line down the pipeline. Sending this to [`Out-Null`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849716.aspx) my memory usage only went up by a few 10's of KB while it was executing on a nearly 2,000,000 line log file (~186 MB):

```
function Get-ContentByLine {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][PsObject]$InputObject
  )

  begin {
    $line = $null
    $fs = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($InputObject)
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fs)
  }

  process {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    while ($line -ne $null) {
        $line
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    }
  }

  end {
    $reader.Dispose();
    $fs.Dispose();
  }
}
```

You would invoke it like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-ContentByLine "C:\really.big.log" | Out-Null
```

Comment: Interesting. Of course using .NET makes sense, but I had never seen begin/process/end before. [Some details](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-function-input.html) for others unfamiliar like me. It'd be awfully nice if PowerShell already had something like this built in.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is suggested by [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/16/working-around-legacy-redirection-issues-with-powershell.aspx). Use the old command line:

```
cmd.exe /C "ECHO < input-file.txt"
```

Older style input redirection does not consume memory in the same manner.

However, this is very ugly and makes you do some strange things to build more complicated commands. I would prefer a pure PowerShell solution.